# Existence and calculation of $\int_{D}x_1x_2x_3dS_2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, manifolds

I want to check if my solution are right. Can someone help me?

I have this problem:

Let $D:=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1+x_2+x_3=1\}$

Show if $\int_{D}x_1x_2x_3dS_2$ exists. If so, calculate it

So we have this formula:
$\int_{φ(U)} f dS_k = \int_{U} (f ◦ φ) (det(Dφ)^T Dφ)^{1/2} dλ_k$

Where $U ⊆ \mathbb{R}^k$ open, $φ ∈ C^1 (U; \mathbb{R}^n )$ such that for all $x ∈ U$ we have rank $Dφ(x) = k$, and such that $φ : U → φ(U)$ is a homoomorphism.

So what I practically need to prove is that:

1. $rank(Dφ(x)) = k$
2. $φ$ is Homoomorphism: $φ$ should be bijective and $φ$ $φ^{-1}$ should be continous

So for 1. I have written for $φ(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,1-x_1-x_2)$ and therefore $Dφ=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 &  1\\ -1&  -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and therefore as rank $2$

2. we can say that $φ$ is continous since $x_1,x_2,1-x_1-x_2$ are continous functions. $φ$ is bijective and it is trivial that $φ^{-1}$ is also continous.

So we can calculate $\int_{D}x_1x_2x_3dS_2$

To do it we first need to calculate $(det(Dφ)^T Dφ)^{1/2}$

It follows: $(det(Dφ)^T Dφ)=det(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 &  1\\ -1&  -1 \end{pmatrix}^T \cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 &  1\\ -1&  -1 \end{pmatrix})=det(\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{matrix}\right))=3$

So we have $\int_{D}x_1x_2x_3dS_2=\sqrt{3}\int_{0}^{1-x_1}\int_{0}^{1} x_1x_2(1-x_1-x_2)dx_1dx_2$

so far everything right? I am not sure about the limits of my integral and the function $φ$. I think that the function may be $φ(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,x_1-x_2)$ and not $φ(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2,1-x_1-x_2)$.

Comment: The expression $$\int_{0}^{1-x_1}\int_{0}^{1} x_1x_2(1-x_1-x_2)\;dx_1\;dx_2$$does not make any sense, better write - with the same intention - $$\int_{0}^{1} dx_1\int_{0}^{1-x_1}x_1x_2(1-x_1-x_2)\;dx_2$$ so that it becomes clear which integral is done w.r.t. which variable. Also, use a limit like $1-x_1$ only inside an integral on $x_1$, else there is no meaning for it. Now we have an easy computation. You can also check if the integral of one (instead of $\varphi$) over $D$ gives the area of the equilateral triangle $D$ with side $\sqrt2$.

Comment: @dan_fulea and my $φ$ is correct, right?

Comment: The composition $f\circ \varphi$ - as it appears in the final integral - is correct, $x_1,x_2$ are kept via $\varphi$, and $x_3$ becomes $(1-x_1-x_2)$, then $f$ takes the product of the three components.